# How to include a photo using this code

Tags: moderncv

I'm trying to achieve these goals:

- Include a photo on the right of `\personaltitle`. (flushright)
- To center the display of `\title` on the head of the page.

Here is my MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,francais]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}
\usepackage{babel}

\firstname{XX}
\familyname{X}
\title{XXXX}              
\address{XXX}    
\email{XX@X.com}  
\mobile{xxxx}
\extrainfo{xxxx}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{%
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}{@{}l@{}}
     {\LARGE\textbf{\@lastname\ \@firstname}} \\
     \@addressstreet \\
     \@addresscity  \\
     \@extrainfo \\
     \mobilephonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
     \emailsymbol:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
 \end{tabular}\par%\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}

\begin{document}
\personaltitle
\section{Intro}
\cventry{PPP OOO \newline{} U UUUU}{DDDDDD}{IIIIII}{AAAA}{BBBBB}{CC}
\end{document}
```

Any brilliant suggestion, please?

Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following modifications to your `\personaltitle` will do:

```
\documentclass[11pt,a4paper,francais]{moderncv}
\moderncvtheme[blue]{classic}                
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[top=1.1cm, bottom=1.1cm, left=2cm, right=2cm]{geometry}
\setlength{\hintscolumnwidth}{2.5cm}
\usepackage{babel}

\firstname{XX}
\familyname{X}
\title{The title}              
\address{XXX}    
\email{XX@X.com}  
\mobile{xxxx}
\extrainfo{xxxx}
\photo{ctanlion}

\makeatletter
\newcommand\personaltitle{%
  \ifthenelse{\equal{\@title}{}}{}{%
  \begin{minipage}{\linewidth}
  \centering
  \titlestyle{\@title}
  \end{minipage}\vskip3ex}
  \def\phonesdetails{}%
  \collectionloop{phones}{% the key holds the phone type (=symbol command prefix), the item holds the number
    \protected@edef\phonesdetails{\phonesdetails\protect\makenewline\csname\collectionloopkey phonesymbol\endcsname\collectionloopitem}}%
 \par\noindent\begin{tabular}[b]{@{}l@{}}
     {\LARGE\textbf{\@lastname\ \@firstname}} \\
     \@addressstreet \\
     \@addresscity  \\
     \@extrainfo \\
     \mobilephonesymbol:\ \collection@phones@item  \\
     \emailsymbol:\ \emaillink{\@email} \\
 \end{tabular}\hfill
 \begin{tabular}[b]{@{}c@{}}
 \color{color1}\framebox{\includegraphics[width=\@photowidth]{\@photo}}
 \end{tabular}\par%\noindent\rule{\linewidth}{1pt}\par%
}

\begin{document}
\personaltitle
\section{Intro}
\cventry{PPP OOO \newline{} U UUUU}{DDDDDD}{IIIIII}{AAAA}{BBBBB}{CC}
\end{document}
```

The result:

[image]

Comment: Do you think it's better to put the title between the personalinfos and the photo or may be under those?